# Angular 6 : How to use css and js files from cshtml pages of mvc into Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to migrate a MVC project into Angular 6.
I have css files and js files in chtml code which are used in the mvc application as below :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/OptumFiles/fonts-clientlibs-global.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/OptumFiles/optum-clientlibs-global.min.css" type="text/css">
<script async="" src="~/OptumFiles/analytics.js"></script>
<script async="" src="~/OptumFiles/js.js"></script>
```

Now i want to use these files in my angular project globally.

**Things i have tried** :

- Created a folder FICAssets in the Angular project.
- Added files in that folder.
- Added their reference in index.html file.

Code in index.html :

```
    <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="FICAssets/css/fonts-clientlibs-global.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="FICAssets/css/optum-clientlibs-global.min.css">
    <script src="FICAssets/js/analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="FICAssets/js/js.js"></script>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

The problem is that iam still not able to load the files , getting 404 error.

[image]

Comment: Assets are set in the `angular.json` file. DId you add it to that file ?

Comment: No, sorry iam not sure how to do that. Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assets aren't magical, they need to be declared as such.

Open your `angular.json` file. Find the path

projects.YourProjectName.architect.build.options.assets

And from there, add your declared folder in it. It should keep the assets up when the project is complied.

Answer (score 0):

1. open your angular.json.
2. add style in "styles": []
3. add script in "scripts": []

reference link :- https://www.truecodex.com/course/angular-6/how-to-include-external-css-and-js-file-in-angular-6-angular-7